# Tilda - Can I make it close on lose focus?

Tags: compiz, guake

Can I make Tilda (or any window for that matter) close on lose focus?

I like Tilda better than Guake but I like the close on lose focus of Guake setting.

Is there a Compiz setting I've forgotten about?

Or something else?

Comment: Anyone have a work-around to make windows close on lose focus? With or without compiz...

Comment: Today I did a google search for how to close tilda on lose focus. This came up and I read it. I then saw my name in the comment above this. I said woah! Then I saw my name as the creator of this question. Jesus, I have a bad memory.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such setting in Tilda, AFAIK.
You could hack similar behaviour using Compiz Widget Layer by specifying terminal window as "Widget Window".
Or you could check for another alternatives.
For example [Stjerm](http://code.google.com/p/stjerm-terminal-emulator/) supports "autohide" and is very lightweight. Two cons here:

1. Unlike Tilda, there's no configuration window, you have to specify all options through command-line or .Xdefaults file
2. Ubuntu package is very old, so you better download and compile stjerm yourself